# Respawn dynamics of command blocks in a Minecraft event

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm designing a parkour event in a Vanilla world totally organized with command blocks.
What I'm trying to do is:

1. Teleport a player in a indoor map in the sky
2. Change his gamemode to Adventure Mod
3. Set his spawn-point at the beginning of the map
4. Let him continue the event
5. At the end of the event teleport him back
6. Change his gamemode to Survival
7. Reset his old spawn-point

Well, I can do everything in this list, except for the point 7..
How can I reset his old spawn-point?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Reset his old spawn-point"?

Comment: Let's assume that this guy has his spawn-point near his bed at 123/65/456. He starts the parkour event and the CB tps him at 456/100/789. When the event is finished he wants to come back and another CB tps him back. During the event, his spawn-point has been setted there in order to let him re-spawn there in case of death. The spawn-point of the event remains setted even if the event has finished.. What can we do?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

Don't set their spawn in the sky, instead make a `deathCount` objective, and at the beginning of the 'event', set it to 0 for all players. When a player dies, teleport them back to the beginning, then set their `deathCount` to 0.

If you are doing a single player map, you could, instead of using beds for spawns, have a button that summons an invisible invincible armor stand, and then use that for the 'resetting' part.

If you are doing this with multiple people on a server, you could also at the beginning of the event, kill all players, then summon an armor stand at each player with a custom name, then use those to set the spawns back.

### How to use /scoreboard

First, make the objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add abc deathCount
```

Then, make a clock going to two command blocks.
In the first block, put

```
/tp @a[score_abc_min=1] <x> <y> <z> (coords of intended spawn)
```

The second block should have

```
/scoreboard players set @a abc 0
```

abc can be replaced with whatever you want

### New answser:

Use a command block close to the middle of the room, (could be on roof or in floor) on a relatively quick timer. Use
`/tp @a[rm=?] <x> <y> <z>`
to teleport everyone at least `?` blocks from the command block to x y z.

Comment: Talk me about this deathCount objective. How can this feature can help me?

Comment: @hiru I don't know how much you know about command blocks, but you can use /scoreboard to track statistics (in this case, deaths). [Here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard) is a good example of how /scoreboard works. I will add some about it in the answer

Comment: Let me see if I got it.. First the player deathCount goes to 0, then the CB activates **only** when the count goes to 1 and if this statement is true, it tps the player at the beginning of the event resetting again the deathCount?

Comment: We have a prob. When I die, the CB tps me in the right coord, but when I click on the button in order to respawn, I respawn in my original spawn-point and not in the event zone

Comment: @hiru What command is the button using? Instead of /kill-ing the player, you could just /tp them to the start

Comment: This is a parkour event, people die. Often. In case of death their corpses are tped in the right position but when they respawn (I'm talking about the buttons in the main menu when the death message popups in front of you) they do that in the wrong place

Comment: @hiru, Okay, I added a different solution to the answer. Make sure that `?` covers all of the parkour area though.